# ffmpeg command is not able capture mobile video image properly. Always getting stretch image

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have tried many ffmpeg commands to capture image from mobile video but it's always getting stretch image output.

There are following commands which I used. My video format is mobile shoot. Desktop video is fine. Only mobile video having problem. Always getting stretch image. I need perfect image horizontally and  vertically without stretch image.

```
$command = "ffmpeg  -i <<input video>> -r 0.0033 -vf scale=-1:120 -vcodec png output.jpg";

$command = "ffmpeg -i <<input video>> -ss 00:00:25 -vframes 1  output.jpg";

$command = "ffmpeg -ss 00:00:45 -i <<input video>> -vframes 1 -q:v 2 output.jpg";

$command = "ffmpeg -i <<input video>> -deinterlace -an -ss 00:00:45 -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y -s 850x478 output.jpg 2>&1";

$command = "ffmpeg -ss 100 -i <<input video>> -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 -vf scale=850:478:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=850:478 output.jpg";
```

Please let me know where I am wrong in above command? Or if you have other command please let me know.

Comment: Does your player also stretch `<<input video>>`? Commands 2 & 3 are not performing any scaling, so there should be no stretching. Perhaps an issue with your player. How can we duplicate this problem?

Comment: There is no issue in player. Output of command to getting stretch image. I need same to same image which I can see in the video. Video is mobile size. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Show the complete log from the ffmpeg process from this command: `ffmpeg -i <<input video>> -ss 00:00:25 -vframes 1  output.jpg`. If you are unable to do so provide a link to the input video.

Comment: @llogan video is porn and site is also porn so I can't share here. I used $command = "ffmpeg -i video_1299a3968b19a2f69442003c1d4cb9056f9.mp4 -ss 00:00:25 -vframes 1  output.jpg";
exec($command); command but still no luck

Comment: You need to show the complete ffmpeg log from that command.